# one block of text coming from database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, text

I have put paragraphs of text into my mongo database using a mongoose schema. It is a lot of text and it just comes out as one giant block of text on my site page. I have tried including html into the paragraphs but it shows the html and remains as one giant blob of text.

My question is: how do I store paragraphs of text in my database and display them as separate paragraphs? Many thanks in advance.

```
name: 'Superstar Road Bike',
               mainImage: '/public/img/Bikes/Road/Superstar Disc/Superstar.jpeg',
               gallery: [ '/public/img/Bikes/Road/Superstar Disc/superstar bottom bracket.jpeg'
                   , '/public/img/Bikes/Road/Superstar Disc/superstar rear.jpeg'
                   , '/public/img/Bikes/Road/Superstar Disc/superstar front end.jpeg'

                ],
               description: '<p>Superstar reinterprets at the highest degree of.</p>in carbon fiber, the legendary Italian competition bicycle on the track, the Cinelli that embodies the brands heritage and DNA.Unlike other brands that every year offer bicycles with an increasingly reduced use destination, Cinelli developed Superstar with a meticulous attention to how the intrinsic qualities of carbon fiber and the production processes could be used to create a tremendous edition contemporary of the legendary Italian Grand Tour quality in the saddle: an intelligent balance of lightness, perfect maneuverability on any surface and comfort over long distances.', 
               price: 39999,
               salePrice: 400,
```

Here is how I am displaying it in my EJS file:

```
<div id="itemParagraph">
    <p> <%= bike.description %> </p>
  </div>
  <div id="colorSeparator"></div>
```

Comment: That looks like a document, is that way is displayed on your site?  How is that retrieved from the database and displayed? We can't really comment on code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Did you parse the return object from the DB?

Comment: I just added how I am displaying it in my EJS file